# Scraping data from ESPNCricInfo StatsGuru in a .csv using Python

Tags: python, html, csv, web-scraping

Please could you advise on how to scrape from the following URL:

https://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;filter=advanced;orderby=innings;size=200;spanmax1=07+Aug+2020;spanmin1=07+Aug+2015;spanval1=span;template=results;type=batting

... so that the result can sit in a table like this:

[image]

The issue I'm having is multiple HTML tags with the same class 'engineTable'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;filter=advanced;orderby=innings;size=200;spanmax1=07+Aug+2020;spanmin1=07+Aug+2015;spanval1=span;template=results;type=batting")[2]
```

Comment: Thank you - the code below worked for me:

df = pd.read_html("https://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;filter=advanced;orderby=innings;size=200;spanmax1=07+Aug+2020;spanmin1=07+Aug+2015;spanval1=span;template=results;type=batting")[2]